# Timeout Solr search

Tags: solr, settimeout, alfresco, solr4

I'm trying to timeout Solr if it takes too long to run a query.

**What I've tried**:

According to Solr documentation there is `timeAllowed` parameter which does exactly what I'm looking for, I've tried to

- add `<int name="timeAllowed">50</int>` to `requestHadnler` in solrConfig.xml;
- add `timeAllowed` parameter to request URL:

```
localhost:8080/solr4/alfresco/select?q=*&timeAllowed=50
```

But it doesn't work (time to load results is more than provided value).

**Why I want to do this:** we implemented access right validation on Solr side and now for some vague queries like `*` it takes too much time for Solr to respond.

Probably it could be possible to close such connections from Alfresco or from web container but then such queries will internally run on Solr slowing down the server.

Comment: did you reload the core after making the changes?

Comment: I assume you have had a read here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557476/timing-out-a-query-in-solr

Comment: Moreover how long do the requests take? What is the QTime in the response header? Solr will just take the time into account the response has on the server, so the time till Solr is hit, the time over the network back to you and the time the client takes to parse the response is not included in the 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `timeAllowed` in milliseconds. `timeAllowed` 50 - This means that you need to complete the request in 50 milliseconds.

Try `timeAllowed` 5000.

Comment: As @YoungHobbit mentioned in the comment, you have to reload the core after making these changes.