# Solr stops giving results after sometime

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I am using Solrj from Java to access Solr. I am querying multiple times in a multithreaded(Using a fixed threadpool of 100) environment, but after some time(somewhere after firing 100k~120k queries) solr stops giving results for search queries, and when I restart Tomcat it starts again.

Couldn't see any exception in tomcat logs.
Found some exceptions in Solr logs.

```
5/1/2016, 6:40:41 PM

ERROR

null

SolrCore

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50000/50000 ms
5/1/2016, 6:40:41 PM

ERROR

null

SolrCore

[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000 ms
5/1/2016, 6:40:41 PM

ERROR

null

SolrDispatchFilter

null:[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000 ms
```

Comment: did you check the logs, what is happening there, any exceptions?

Comment: Yes, I checked tomcat logs. No exception there.

Comment: it stops means, it hangs or return empty results... what?

Comment: Checked Solr Logs. Can see a lot of these exceptions. Could this be reason?
 
ERROR
 
null
 
SolrCore
 
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50000/50000 ms
ERROR
 
null
 
SolrCore
 
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000 ms
5/1/2016, 6:40:41 PM
 
ERROR
 
null
 
SolrDispatchFilter
 
null:[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 50001/50000ms

Comment: If you add the exception and extra information to the post then it will readable. I would suggest never add extra information to comment section. Provide in the post itself so that will be easily available to everyone.

Comment: There are several chances to run into a timeout. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557476/timing-out-a-query-in-solr. Timeout settings of your container (Tomcat, Jetty) or the timeAllowed parameter of Solr maybe the culprit. But anyway, check the runtime of your queries! They should not last that long.